Angular is not detecting changes
I am having a problem with Angular not detecting when an array has no elements.
Parent:
<child
   [trainingData]="trainingData"
>             
</child>

Child:
@Input() set trainingData(value: any) {
   ...
}

Parent changes trainingData. It can add more elements or remove some.
It adds elements by doing:
trainingData = trainingData.concat(newdata);

Or removes some elements by doing filter:
trainingData = trainingData.filter (elem => {
    return "some condition";
})

all of this works fine, except when all elements are filtered out and trainingData becomes an empty array. In this case the child is not getting the new value.
Both parent and child have this:
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Please help.
Thanks
Update: working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9wyuuu-2ngzio?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts

Can you provide a stackblitz repro ? It's a bit hard to investigate with this bit of information

When you concat it does not change the array reference ( arrays are stored as references( locations in memory ) you need to reset the reference to a new reference when doing insert/update/delete operations using array destructuring
After you do a create/update/delete, just create a shallow copy ( creates a new reference in memory for the array ) so that the child will trigger change detection since the memory location has been updated
// after doing a create/update/delete
this.trainingData = [...this.trainingData]; // creates a new reference in memory!


Check my comment above.

@Mark trainingData.length = 0 is not something you can set, you can only modify the array, the length is a calculated field!

@Mark Please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging, also update the same on the question!

I have an example where everything works and I cannot replicate the problem.

@Mark If your repo is public then share the link

@NarenMurali just fyi: ofc u can set array length... besides this u got the point I guess
